# Linear algebra, help understanding Cayley + Jordan form

Tags: linear-algebra

On page 107 of Evan Chen's [Napkin](http://web.evanchen.cc/napkin.html), I don't understand why T is indecomposable means there is an eigenvalue.
On page 110 I don't get how $(X- \lambda )^d$ is the zero map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand why T is indecomposable means there is an eigenvalue.

Jordan form $J$ of a matrix $A$ is

$$
J = M^{-1}AM=\begin{bmatrix}
       J_1 &  \\ 
        & . \\
        & & .\\
        & & &J_s
    \end{bmatrix}\qquad(1)
$$

where each block $J_i$ is a Jordan block, given by
$$
J_i = \begin{bmatrix}
       \lambda_i & 1 \\ 
        & \lambda_i & . \\
        & & . &1\\
        & & &\lambda_i
    \end{bmatrix}\qquad(2)
$$

This Jordan block represents a single eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ of the matrix $A$

So $T$ is indecomposable means that $T$ is of the form $J_i$, in this case $T:V_1 \to V_1 $ , $V_1 = [J_1]$ 
and since $J_1$ represents a single eigenvalue of $A$, there is an eigenvalue.

> I don't get how $(X−λ)^d$ is the zero map.

From Pg.110 of the pdf you linked,

$$
p_T(X) = (X−λ_1I)^{d_1}(X−λ_2I)^{d_2}...(X−λ_mI)^{d_m}
$$

Writing each $X$ in its Jordan form, $X = MJM^{-1}$,
$$
p_T(J) = (MJM^{-1}−λ_1MM^{-1})^{d_1}(MJM^{-1}−λ_2MM^{-1})^{d_2}...(MJM^{-1}−λ_mMM^{-1})^{d_m}
$$

$$
p_T(J) = \bigl(M(J-λ_1I)M^{-1}\bigr)^{d_1}\bigl(M(J-λ_2I)M^{-1}\bigr)^{d_2}...\bigl(M(J-λ_mI)M^{-1}\bigr)^{d_m}
$$

Now concentrating on each $J-λ_iI$, from eq(1) and eq(2), this produces an upper triangular block matrix with $0$s on diagonal. For each term in the product, there are $0$s on corresponding diagonals and their product will result in a Zero matrix.

Edit:

Explanation on how T acts independently on each subspace of Jordan block (pg. 105 of pdf linked).

Let's say for a $T:V \to V$ such that T has a complete set of independent eigenvectors. Taking the example given in the pdf:

$$
T = \begin{bmatrix}
\ 3\\
& 7\\
& & 2\\
& & & 2\\
& & & & 5\\
& & & & & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

For this matrix, the eigenvectors are $3e_1, 7e_2, 2e_3, 2e_4, 5e_5, 3e_6$ and each eigenvector has an eigenspace.

When $T$ acts on each of the eigenspace (of each eigenvector), to produce $Tv = \lambda v$, these are also independent since they are scalar multiples of independent eigenvectors.

Now suppose that $T$ cannot be diagonalized and a complete set of independent eigenvectors cannot be extracted. In that case, lets say $\lambda_1$ is a repeated eigenvalue and $\lambda_2$ is a single eigenvalue, for which $\lambda_1$ has only one independent eigenvector $v_1$ and $\lambda_2$ has eigenvector $v_2$.

Now in order to produce an upper triangular matrix in Jordan form, we choose the basis as $v_1$, $v_1'$ and $v_2$ such that, $Tv_1 = \lambda_1 v_1$, $Tv_2 = \lambda_2 v_2$ and finally $Tv_1' = v_1 + \lambda_1 v_1'$. i.e. check that

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\ v_1'\\
v_1\\
v_2
\end{bmatrix}
T = J
\begin{bmatrix}
\ v_1'\\
v_1\\
v_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where
$$
J = \begin{bmatrix}
\ \lambda_1 & 1 \\
& \lambda_1 \\
& & \lambda_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Multiply yourself and verify.

This gives us the Jordan form, $VT = JV$ $\Rightarrow$ $VAV^{-1} = J$

So to conclude, $T$ applies painlessly on $v_2$ to produce a diagonal element. In order to transform T to a form which is as diagonal as possible, we had to take a basis vector $v_1'$ along with $v_1$ which produces a Jordan block with diagonal elements and an extra '1' above the diagonal. Applying T on this basis (which is actually a subspace of $v_1$), produced an independent Jordan block. This when translated to n dimensions, shows that T applies independently on each subspace of $v$ to give its constituent Jordan blocks.

Comment: Thx, another question, on page 105, they said ''T acts on each of these subspaces independently. These subspaces correspond to the
blocks in the matrix above''. What exactly do they mean by this?

Comment: Each block corresponds to a single eigenvector. All these eigenvectors are independent and so T acts on each of them independently. Does this answer your question? If not I will add a detailed explanation.

Comment: Could you add a detailed explanation please?

Comment: @RayOfHope Please see my edit above. Hope this clears your doubt

Comment: Great, thanks!!